# Particular Big endian little endian representation of 0x12345678?

Tags: arm, endianness

**mem32[&100]=&12345678 If big-endian addressing is used what is mem8[&101]?**

I am getting the answer 56 and here is my reasoning;

In my understanding; in big endian system, the most significant byte is stored first in memory so i.e.:

```
0x100 0x101 0x102 0x103
78    56    34    12
```

But the "correct" answer is 34.

Could someone explain why?/ Tell me that answer is wrong?

EDIT: I realised my mistake. For a moment I forgot the number at the left end is the most significant!

Comment: Why you would tag this arm?

Comment: Please add some appropriate tags to this - it certainly doesn't seem to be an ARM question - I'd remove the tag, but since it's not got any other I can't. 

As for the question, in absence of any clue as to the notation your are using, what does mem32[x] and mem[y] do?

Comment: I added the tag ARM because I happened to be studying questions for the ARM instruction set. I realised my mistake as soon as I posted but I couldn't find a way to delete the post?

Comment: ARM if not others has two big endian modes and the transaction size plus mode determine what the byte view of memory is, it not some 1980s motorola view of things.   The tag is very relevant to providing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

ARM in particular but you have to be careful with endians.  In general read the documentation for the processor.  ARM has two big endian representations, and which one your ARM supports is based on 1) age/history and 2) transaction type.

If you are on an older arm that is BE-32 or word invariant, then a 32 bit transaction in big endian mode is the same as a little endian transaction and from a byte perspective the result of 0x12345678 at address 0x100 is (for both big and little endian):

```
0x100 78
0x101 56
0x102 34
0x103 12
```

If you were to write as a word and then read back as bytes (in big endian mode) that is what you would see.

If you are on a more modern ARM which is BE-8 or byte invariant then a 32 bit (DATA) big endian write of 0x12345678 would give, from a byte perspective:

```
0x100 12
0x101 34
0x102 56
0x103 78
```

When reading it back as bytes with those addresses (in big or little endian mode).

But on BE-8 a write of 0x34 to 0x101 gives:

```
0x101 0x34
```

in both big endian and little endian mode of the processor. It is byte invariant.

The instructions are still little endian all the time on be-8 systems making the compiler just that much more of the nightmare that it already is. (Read and fetch give different results for the same address when in big endian mode).

In general for ARM or in general in general, use the native endian of the architecture even if the architecture claims big and little support.  Much more likely to find tools that work and much more likely to have fewer bugs in the tools.  Some vendors for some insane reason have arm based cores that are big endian mode only, granted the one I am thinking of also has a little endian version, buy that one.

A simple web search now that you know what to look for will find charts of how the programmers view of memory looks between BE-8 and BE-32 for the different transaction sizes on ARM's web site.

If you are interested in other architectures then look those specific details up.  And always do your system engineering, if someone or somewhere there is a reference to endianness, do not instantly assume you are byte swapping, what you do and how you do it falls out for free and is correct if you just do your system engineering.  Many folks get it wrong and struggle to understand why when making these kinds of assumptions.  We should really remove big and little endian from our vocabulary as it just creates more confusion than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

For the 32 bit value `0x12345678`, `12` is the most significant byte, and this comes first on a big endian system, followed by `34`, `56`, `78`.

Big endian:

```
0x100 12
0x101 34
0x102 56
0x103 78
```

Little endian:

```
0x100 78
0x101 56
0x102 34
0x103 12
```

Comment: yes for byte invariant word sized data transfers, but not for word invariant word sized data transfers.

Answer (score 0):

You got it the wrong way round:

```
0x100 0x101 0x102 0x103
78    56    34    12
```

This is 0x78563412 in BIG endian, or 0x12345678 in LITTLE endian.

The 32 Bit value 0x12345678 in BIG endian is `12 34 56 78`.

Comment: yes for byte invariant word sized data transfers, but not for word invariant word sized data transfers.

Comment: OP is talking about ARM in big endian mode (which almost nobody uses these days). A word write of 0x12345678 will put bytes into memory in the byte order from this post above, i.e. 12 34 56 78.

Comment: I am talking about arm in big endian mode and there are two big endian modes, byte invarant and word invariant.  that have different results and depend on what access size you do as to the results (byte, halfword, word).  Not possible to describe arm big endian in one small description

Comment: ti was defaulting one of their product lines to big endian for some insane reason (product designed/forced to big endian, had a secondary product in little).  Marvell bought the xscales from intel, not sure if they are still making a product.  but yes, very rarely used.