# How does the computer stores the values in memory?

Tags: assembly, memory

am learning assembly and I have been wondering how exactly does computer stores the memory works for example : there is a decimal value of 200078 which is 0x30D8E in hex and 110000110110001110 in binary as far as I know each address holds one byte of data so if we store this value in the memory as and represent in binary using little endian will it be like this:

```
Address | Value
0x100   | 10001110
0x101   | 00001101
0x102   | 00000011
```

and if we represent it in hex will it look something like this

```
Address | Value
0x100   | 8E
0x101   | 0D
0x102   | 03
```

because we are not adding the values in these memory addresses like `8E + OD + 03` to get the value we want but instead we are putting them like a "string" and laying them from the starting, like we will first put `E` and then `8` before that which will make it `8E` and then `D` before that and now it will be `D8E` and so on, right? or am i wrong and the memory stores the values in a different way?

Comment: Memory is byte-addressable.  4-bit nibbles (hex digits) within bytes aren't part of the how memory addressing works, just a matter of what you do with the bits once it gets into the CPU and you can do stuff like right-shift to isolate a nibble.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Particular Big endian little endian representation of 0x12345678?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225578/particular-big-endian-little-endian-representation-of-0x12345678)

Comment: If you want to delve into the nitty gritty of the hardware, I recommend Ulrich Drepper's [What every compute programmer should know about memory](https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf) with some outdated passages noted [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126311/how-much-of-what-every-programmer-should-know-about-memory-is-still-valid)

Comment: @RaymondChen: unfortunately [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225578/particular-big-endian-little-endian-representation-of-0x12345678) is tagged [arm], and old_timer's new answer explains that things aren't so simple across historical vs. newer ARMs, so the simple answers that would cover this question aren't sufficient for an ARM endianness question.

Comment: You have the right idea, just should work 8 bit values, 2 hex digits at a time instead of 1 at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When considering a 32 bit value for example 0x12345678.  Being stored at address 0x200.  From a byte address perspective and if you were to write the 32 bit word to 0x200 then do byte reads of these addresses this is what you would find (for a little endian arm).

```
0x200 0x78
0x201 0x56
0x202 0x34
0x203 0x12
```

If the thought of a string or an array helps the understanding then yes.  From a byte address perspective the number is broken in to bytes and the least significant byte (the little end) is first, meaning the lowest address.

Same would go for a 16 bit value 0xAABB

```
0x302 0xBB
0x303 0xAA
```

Where you went off the rails is trying to then understand the mechanism as to how it gets to memory.  It is not 4 bits at a time. Furthermore hexadecimal notation or decimal or octal or other is for the convenience of the humans.  The computer stores bits, the 16 bit value 0b10101010101101011 is the same as 0xAABB, just easier for humans to carry the 0xAABB around when communicating to each other or when writing software.  The two versions of that 16 bit value is just that same 16 bit value and the memory stores it as individual bits (written all at once in this case).

What memory actually looks like and how these bits get there is a much longer story.

Comment: Ok so i was right at the binary thing that the memory stores the data like that but the hex thing that I did was nonsense as it is only for our own convenience?

Comment: re-wrote answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, just should work with 8 bit values — 2 hex digits at a time —instead of 1 at a time.

We don't know the storage order of binary digits (or hex digits) within a single byte because we cannot address individual bits.

Endianess is a natural consequence of:

- addressability of individual items, and,
- the use of multiple addresses to store what we think of as a single item.

These two concepts together immediately give rise to the question of the order of individually addressable items to make the whole larger item.  When loading a multi-address item, we must use the same endianness that was used to store it or else the larger data item comes back as if scrambled.

Importantly, we can test for what endian is being used by storing a known multibyte item and ***consulting the individual bytes*** of the for their values, thus, endianness is visible/observable in the architecture of programs, certainly at the machine code level.

Where we do not have one (addressability) or the other (multi-address items), we do not have endianness.

For example, CPU registers (on the vast majority of architectures, including x86, MIPS, ARM, and RISC V) are named but are not addressable, so we cannot view the storage order of bytes (or bits) within them — thus, there is no endianness involved with CPU registers.  Once a multibyte items is store to byte addressable memory, there is endianness *in memory*.  But within the CPU register itself, *we cannot test* and thus cannot know the endianness being used therein.

As another example, within a single byte in memory we cannot test the endianness of the individual bits.  We can only read or write a whole byte, so have no mechanism to test for bit storage order.  If we could read an individual bit we could do an endianness test but we cannot and so we can never know the bit storage order.  We have only the guarantee that a byte stored will hold the value we put there for later retrieval.

Processors that offer multibyte loads & stores necessarily have to choose an endian to use.  If the processor didn't offer multi-byte loads and stores, then the choice of endianness would be made in software, as a program manipulating 4 byte items would have to decide the storage order of each of the 4 bytes, and encode individual byte store/load instructions to transfer multi byte items between memory and the CPU.

Even when the processor has an endianness, software has to work with items whose size & layout is larger than naturally supported by multibyte loads & stores, so, then it is up to the software to choose ordering of piece parts to make the larger wholes.  (Generally, going with the same endianness of the processor compiled for.)

And finally, let's note that some languages like Java go to lengths to hide endianness, by denying individual byte addressability of some multi-address items like int or double.  In Java, we can convert an int to a sequence of 4 bytes, but we (the software) have to decide the storage order then and there without depending on the endianness of the processor.

Comment: SIMD registers are addressable by shuffle indexes like x86 [`pshufb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufb) or ARM `vtbl`.  x86 integer registers are also sub-addressable but only by names, like AL and AH being the low 2 bytes of RAX.  ([How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191178)).  Similarly, ARM vector regs like `q0` being composed of `d1:d0` which in turn is `s3:s2:s1:s0`.  Whole-register ops like left or right shift do interact with this.  But in all cases, SIMD indexing or partial registers are defined separately from memory endianness.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Good discussion.  Let me ask what is the relative ***order*** of `AL` vs. `AH`?  I say there is none because these are aliases/names not numeric addresses.  Certainly there is a solid definition of `AL` and `AH`, but not an ordering of their names.  Whereas when (say `AX`) stored to memory we have addresses that are numeric and thus necessarily ordered/orderable.

Comment: Like I said, whole-register ops like left or right shift do interact with this, so we know `AL` is the low 8 bits and AH is the high 8 bits.  After `mov eax, 0x1234`, AL=0x34.  After `shr eax, 8`, AL=0x12.   But yes, the argument for comparing this to endianness is much stronger for SIMD registers where there is numerical indexing with runtime-variable shuffle indices, as in `pshufb`, unlike with 8-bit register numbers in machine code where AL= register #0, AH= register #4.

Comment: With `pshufb`, we have indices from 0 to 15 for each byte, and we also have whole-register `psrldq xmm0, 3` to right shift the register by 3 bytes, or `psrlq xmm0, 24` to right-shift each 64-bit half by 24 bits.  And we can also index a vector register with different element widths, e.g. via `pextrd eax, xmm0, 1` to get the 2nd dword, bytes 4..7.  So we have both byte and dword indexing into the same "address space" (16-byte register), and bit-shifts, which is sufficient to say that it's little-endian.

Comment: I tried to write a longer, generic, answer like this, and like this answer, there are a number of problems.  Tried to comment on them but too many to list.   A specific architecture is much easier to talk about.